# Google sign-in always returns false

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

I've implemented Google+ sign-in into my app, when I try to sign-in, the `GoogleSignInResult` returns something to the effect of `com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInResult@c0d0340` though when `result` is passed to `isSuccess` it always returns `false`.

Does anyone know why this is?

For clarification, I followed the G+ login guide and also obtained the `google-services.json` file even though it said it wasn't needed therefore, I also placed my app ID in the `strings.xml`too.

I also ensured `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:2.0.0-alpha6'` was placed in the app level gradle build file and both `compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.4.0' compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.4.0'` was placed in the app level gradle build file. But I'm still not having success.

Other Google searches suggested clearing the Google services cache which I've tried after every build along with my app's cache and data.

Logcat also doesn't report any errors. I'm quite stumped at the moment.

Comment: Hum, it mysteriously now works fine, Google possibly had intermittent server issues maybe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out I might have fixed it by reverting back to the SDK build tools version `23.0.2`, maybe something went wrong with slightly newer build tools `23.0.3` although my Gradle build file is still set to use the newer version it now seems work correctly.